# Can "da- words" be used for humans as well as objects?

Tags: grammar

I was speaking to a friend of mine about another person and I almost used "davon" to refer to a human. Is this allowed?

For example:

I realise it is legal for the following to take place:

> Ich hab ein neues Auto.
>
> Hast du Bilder davon?

In the above example, I used davon to refer to an object, but can I refer to a human in the same way?

> Kennst du meinen Bruder?
>
> Ich bin nicht sicher. Hast du Bilder davon?

I hope I have articulated my question clearly enough but if not, my apologies in advance.

Comment: You, or I, indeed might be misunderstanding what *da-* refers to. Comparing "Hast du Bilder dabei" gives a rather abstract sense, just as with *daher*. So it most often refers to the whole phrase. "Mein Bruder hat Geburtstag gefeiert"-"Hast du Bilder davon". Although, you are not wrong in your perception that it implied the Auto, perhaps as the nearest position of the corefferent. I could nevertheless understand "Hast du Bilder davon, von der etwaigen Bekannschaft?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually you'd say

> Hast du Bilder von ihm?

*Davon* is used for objects, not for humans. You can, however, use *davon* in the following context:

> Mein Bruder ist gestern in den Fluss gefallen.
>   Witzig! Hast du Bilder davon?

You can use it here, because *davon* does not refer to the brother, but to the act of him falling into the river.

---

On your question whether this rule can be generalized:

Well, you can't say that in general, as most of the pronomial adverbs listed [here](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/PronAdv/Form.html?lang=en) for example would not be used when talking about humans in the first place, but very well on actions connected to humans, for example

> Mein Bruder war auch dabei.
>   Ich habe nichts dagegen, dass dein Bruder mitkommt.

However, you can not say

> Magst du meinen Bruder?
>   Ich habe nichts dagegen.

Instead you'd say

> Ich habe nichts gegen ihn.

On the other hand you could safely say (for example when showing a photograph):

> Das sind mein Bruder und mein Vater. Daneben/davor/dahinter/dazwischen steht meine Schwester.

Or also

> Neben/vor/hinter/zwischen ihnen steht meine Schwester.